# SoftLayer order from quote

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have customized quote from SL, when placing order I use the following method:

```
guest = {'hostname': 'test', 'domain': 'example.com'}
container = client['Billing_Order_Quote'].getRecalculatedOrderContainer(id=quote_id)
container['quantity'] = 1
container['hardware'] = []
container['hardware'].append(guest)
container['presetId'] = None
```

To place an order I use placeOrder method:

```
client['Product_Order'].placeOrder(container)
```

I noticed the container gets revalidated every time order is about to be placed and gets changed/adjusted against the standard catalog. In the end my order is not the same as in the quote, all the customizations are not present. Is there any chance to get exactly what is in the quote?

Comment: I think that you mean that original prices are being changed for the standard prices, well if that is the case it seems an issue with the RecalculateOrderContainer I suggest you to open a ticket in softlayer

Comment: I have doubled the network cards in the original quote thus the pricing is also doubled. When using API call mentioned above the double network is gone and in the end I get the "standard" setup.

Comment: well the way that you are using to order the quote is the same as the control portal uses, likely you got the same issue using the control portal and it is probably a bug in softlayer